# "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine" - No request being sent

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make a fairly simple `POST` request to a .NET WebAPI. The request is being made from an Azure Function, in case that makes a difference.

Here's the code:

```
public async Task SetBackupRecordAsync(BackupRecord backupRecord)
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(backupRecord),
                                    Encoding.UTF8,
                                    "application/json");

    var uri = new Uri(_httpClient.BaseAddress, "backup");

    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    try
    {
        result = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        {
            return;
        }

        throw new Exception($"Unexpected response: The API responded with {(int) result.StatusCode} ({result.StatusCode}) when setting the backup record.");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And this is the JSON content which is being included:

> {"AddedById":14000,"AddedOnUtc":"2019-06-17T09:43:25.9821306Z","Backup":false,"DeletedById":null,"DeletedOnUtc":null,"Id":"4c3ef086-3e2a-4964-bdc1-f5e72f525fbd","LastBackupUtc":null,"Name":"something"}

I've also tried setting every property to a non-null value, which made no difference.

Unlike other questions on the same exception message, this request doesn't even get sent - as soon as `_httpClient.PostAsync` is called an exception is thrown:

> An error occurred while sending the request.

The inner exception says

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

And the inner stack trace is quite short:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Some additional points:

- I can see from Fiddler that no request is being put on the wire so there must be - as the top-level exception says - something about the request itself which is preventing it from being sent.
- If I try to hit the same API method from Postman, using exactly the same JSON content, then it works.
- I'm able to successfully make `GET` requests to the same API from the same Azure Function.

So what's wrong with this request?